# xsd in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xml-serialization, schema

I have xsd file. I want to generate my entity model from this schema and serialize and deserialize. What is the recomanded .net framework and C# way to do so? I know JAXB from java. Can I use entity framework? is there another framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate classes from XSD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260001/generate-classes-from-xsd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xsd.exe is your friend. It generates c# classes from your schema. It's a command-line tool  bundled into VisualStudio: open a Vsiaul Studio command prompt, then xsd.exe /? for details

Alternately, Xsd2Code does the same kind of job but integrates better into VisualStudio (it's an add-in). You'll find it on codeplex.com

As far as I know, you can't use EF with a 'generic' xsd schema.

Btw, iPad is not a great tool to type rich text answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used Xsd2Code in my previous project and it was pretty good. [Click here](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/)