# compile schemas with included xsd files

Tags: c#, .net, validation, xsd, xmlschemaset

I have static method, which i use to validate a XML File against a XSD File. This works fine, until there is an XSD File which includes another XSD File.

Example, where i got troubles:

**TYPES.XSD:**

```
<xs:simpleType name="MY_AMOUNT">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999.99"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="-999999999999.99"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="14"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**MAIN.XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="TYPES.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="ROOT">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="SOMEREF1"/>
                <xs:element ref="SOMEREF2"/>
                <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="MY_AMOUNT" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**VALIDATION CODE:**

```
public static class XmlUtils
{
    private static string Errors = string.Empty;

    public static bool ValidateAgainstXSD(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath, ref string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
                | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
                | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);
            settings.Schemas.Compile();

            settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                {
                    Errors += args.Message + "\n";
                }
            };

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) { }
            }

            message = Errors ?? string.Empty;
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Errors);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = "# error validating xml file: " + e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow it seems i have to specify the path of the included XSD File but i have no idea where.

The error occurs at `settings.Schemas.Compile();` , where it says that the type "MY_AMOUNT" is not declared. I read about custom XmlResolvers but to be honest i didn't get that working.

If this is important for an answer: The xsd files are always located in the same directory!

The method is called likes this:

```
string msg = string.Empty;
string basedir = @"C:\Temp";
string xml = Path.Combine(basedir, "XML_FILE.xml");
string xsd = Path.Combine(basedir, "MAIN.xsd");

if (XmlUtils.ValidateAgainstXSD(xml, xsd, ref msg))
{
    // do some work
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help is highly appreciated - Thank you!

### **UPDATE 2016-12-05:**

I wrote my own XmlUrlResolver, to see what happens behind the scenes:

```
internal class XUrlResolver : XmlUrlResolver
{
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
        return base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);
    }

    public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
    {
        return base.ResolveUri(baseUri, relativeUri);
    }
}
```

And the i just try to do:

```
XmlSchemaSet xset = new XmlSchemaSet();
xset.XmlResolver = new XUrlResolver();
xset.Add("", xsdFilePath);
xset.Compile();
```

What happens now (on line `xset.Add`):

1. `XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(null,"C:\\Temp\\MAIN.XSD")` --> `{file:///C:/Temp/MAIN.xsd}`
2. `XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(null,"C:\\Temp\\MAIN.XSD")` --> `{file:///C:/Temp/MAIN.xsd}`
3. `XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity({file:///C:/Temp/MAIN.xsd})` --> Filestream to MAIN.xsd
4. `XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri({file:///C:/Temp/MAIN.xsd},"TYPES.XSD")` --> `{file:///C:/Temp/TYPES.xsd}`
5. `XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity({file:///C:/Temp/TYPES.xsd})` --> Filestream to TYPES.xsd

Looks good to me (except the first 2 Calls are equal!?!) - the path to TYPES.XSD is resolved as it should.

Nevertheless, `xset.Compile()` throws an Exception: "Type MY_AMOUNT is not declared"

And i have no idea why :/

Comment: It looks like you need to add a path to the schema file : schemaLocation="TYPES.xsd"

Comment: i think there must be a solution without changes inside the XSD files.

Comment: The location of the schema may need to be moved.  Mot sure where the defaults should be located.  Maybe something like following webpage will work : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.severity.aspx

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503635/xsd-in-net-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make your xsd files valid.

Types.xsd (added schema root element and xs namespace)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="MY_AMOUNT">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999.99"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="-999999999999.99"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="14"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Main.xsd (removed invalid refs).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="TYPES.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="ROOT">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>                
                <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="MY_AMOUNT" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After that, given that both xsd files are in the same directory, your schemas will compile fine.

Comment: No - still the same problem.

Comment: Then you need to update your code\schemas, because I verified it works by copy-pasting your exact code provided.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this very same issue.

I'm not suggesting this is the *correct* answer, but I got around it by setting the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property to be the path where the included XSDs were located. Then it all processed just fine.