# Issue with reading multiple xml nodes instead of one

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

The XML bills usually have one Node that is returned and parsed. We have come across an issue where an XML bill had multiple Nodes. Since the code is not set up to handle that, the customer ended up with an incorrect bill.

This is the code I have that goes through the bill list. If it comes back with a node then it parses the information from the xml.

```
    var response = new List<CustomerBill>();
    try
    {
        foreach (GetBillForCAResponse eBillResponse in eBillResponseList)
        {
            var statementDetailsResponse =   GetStatementDetails(
                new GetStatementDetailsRequest
                {
                   BatchId = eBillResponse.BatchId,
                   CustomerAccountId =    eBillResponse.CA.ToString("000000000"),
                   StatementId =   eBillResponse.CAS_NUM.ToString("0000")
                });

           string xmlBill = statementDetailsResponse.StatementAsXML.ToString();
           var document = new XmlDocument();
           document.LoadXml(xmlBill);

           var saDetailedPageNode = XmlBillParser.GetDetailPageSectionBySa(requestSa, xmlBill);
           if (saDetailedPageNode == null) continue;

           var customerBill = new CustomerBill();
           customerBill.IsSurepay = XmlBillParser.GetSurepayFlagFromBill(document);
           customerBill.ServiceAddress = XmlBillParser.GetServiceAddress(requestSa, document);
           customerBill.monthName = XmlBillParser.GetnillStatementDate(requestSa, xmlBill);
           customerBill.EqCurlPlanBal = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerCurrentPlanBalance(document);
           customerBill.EqPymntDue = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerPaymentDue(document);

           customerBill.Service = GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(requestSa, xmlBill, saDetailedPageNode);
           response.Add(customerBill);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trace.Write(new InvalidOperationException(requestSa, ex));
    }
    return response;
}
```

Here is the method that checks if there is a node in the XML. I have changed the code so that is returns all the nodes. I had to change the type xmlNode to xmlNodeList because now its returning a collection of nodes. ****This is whats causing all the problems in my code in other places.***

```
public static xmlNode GetDetailPageSectionBySa(string sa, string statementXml)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(statementXml);
    string requestSa = sa.PadLeft(9, '0');
    string xpath = String.Format("//Para[IRBILGP_SA_SAA_ID_PRINT.SERVICE.ACCOUNT.STATMENT='{0}S{1}']/..", requestSa.Substring(0, 4), requestSa.Substring(4));
    return document.SelectNodes(xpath);
    //var nodes = document.SelectNodes(xpath);
   // if(nodes.Count > 0) return nodes[nodes.Count - 1];
    //if(!SaExistInBill(requestSa, statementXml)) return null;
    //var node = GetDetailPageSectionByBillPrisminfoIndex(sa, statementXml);
    //if (node != null) return node;
    //return null;
}
```

So returning back to where it is called.. im getting an invalid arguement here
`customerBill.Service = GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(requestSA, xmlBill, saDetailedPageNode);` because the parameter `saDetailedPageNode` is `xmlNodeList` now when it is expecting of type `xmlNode`. if i go to the method `private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNode detailPageNode)` which i added at the end of this code so you could see. If I change the parameter `XmlNode detailPageNode` to `XmlNodeList detailPageNode` which I have to do to fix the invalid arguement above, I get that `detailPageNode.SelectNodes` becomes invalid because `xmlNodeList` does not have `SelectNodes` as an extension method. I use this extention method a lot through this method. So I am getting a lot of errors.

```
           var saDetailedPageNode = XmlBillParser.GetDetailPageSectionBySa(requestSa, xmlBill);
           if (saDetailedPageNode == null) continue;

           var customerBill = new CustomerBill();
           customerBill.IsSurepay = XmlBillParser.GetSurepayFlagFromBill(document);
           customerBill.ServiceAddress = XmlBillParser.GetServiceAddress(requestSa, document);
           customerBill.monthName = XmlBillParser.GetnillStatementDate(requestSa, xmlBill);
           customerBill.EqCurlPlanBal = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerCurrentPlanBalance(document);
           customerBill.EqPymntDue = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerPaymentDue(document);

           customerBill.Service = GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(requestSa, xmlBill, saDetailedPageNode);
           response.Add(customerBill);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trace.Write(new InvalidOperationException(requestSa, ex));
    }
    return response;
}
    private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNode detailPageNode)
    {
        var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
        saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

        var meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kWh_b"); 

        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kWh_a");
        }
        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("APSElec_kWh_b");
        }
        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("APSElec_kWh_a");
        }

        var demandXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kW_Total_Bold");
```

How can i fix my invalid arguments so that I can use xmlNodeList instead of xmlNode? is there a way to convert or cast? or is there another xml object I can use?

Since I am now returning multiple nodes. I know that I will need to loop through the `customerBill` portion. How can I do that without creating a new bill for every node? All the nodes in one xml need to be included in one bill.

Comment: This seems like you want somebody to do the refactoring work for you; you seemingly understand what you need to do so why not just go ahead and do it?

Comment: I am pretty new programmer. As i understand what i need to do, I am unsure on how to do it. I have done as much as i know how. Any help or guidance would help

Comment: Mayby you should use xmlserializer instead, it may simplifye your code, if you feal it is suitable for you. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850559/change-xml-structure-with-linq-and-having-a-foreach-issue/29850793#29850793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've provided, the only part that needs to account for your refactor to `XmlNodeList` is `GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail()`, so you have two options:

1. Update `GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail()` to take in an `XmlNodeList` parameter instead and aggregate values inside that method to come up with your final `ServiceAddressBillDetail` object.
2. Loop through your `XmlNode` objects in the `XmlNodeList` and reconcile the different `ServiceAddressBillDetail` objects yourself.

Without details on what `ServiceAddressBillDetail`, I can only guess as to which is better, but I'd suggest using the first option.

```
private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(
    string requestSA, 
    string xmlBill, 
    XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
{
   var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
   saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

    foreach(XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
    {
        var meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kWh_b"); 

        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kWh_a");
        }
        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("APSElec_kWh_b");
        }
        if (meterReadEndXMLNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            meterReadEndXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("APSElec_kWh_a");
        }

        var demandXMLNodes = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Usage_kW_Total_Bold");
        //Whatever comes next
    }
}
```

Assuming `ServiceAddressBillDetail` has properties for "usage" you could simply add the appropriate values from each `detailPageNode` to the `saBillDetail` object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. last question for you. I need to loop through the customerBill section im using a 'foreach(var saDetailedPageNode in xmlBillParser.GetDetailPageSectionBySA(requestSA, xmlBill)` but im getting an error. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: i am looping through var customerBill = new CustomerBill();
customerBill.IsSurepay = XmlBillParser.GetSurepayFlagFromBill(document);
 customerBill.ServiceAddress = XmlBillParser.GetServiceAddress(requestSa, document);
           customerBill.monthName = XmlBillParser.GetnillStatementDate(requestSa, xmlBill);
customerBill.EqCurlPlanBal = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerCurrentPlanBalance(document);
customerBill.EqPymntDue = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerPaymentDue(document);
customerBill.Service = GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(requestSa, xmlBill, saDetailedPageNode); and then returning response

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what is going on but this may be the problem;

```
string xpath = String.Format("//Para..
```

The "//" will search in the entire document, but you probably want to search for descendent elements.

Here's some code to deal with a similar problem;

```
XmlNodeList staffNodes = resultXML.SelectNodes("//staff");
List<TempStaff> tempStaffs = staffNodes
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(
        i =>
            new TempStaff()
            {
                StaffId = i.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText,
                Forename = i.SelectSingleNode("forename").InnerText,
                Surname = i.SelectSingleNode("surname").InnerText,
            }
    ).ToList();
```

My XML looks like

```
<staff><forename>asdf</forename><surname>ddsf</surname><id>123</id>... </staff>
<staff><forename>asdfas</forename><surname>asffdf</surname><id>456</id>...</staff>
```

Comment: any guidance or examples on what i need to change that to in order to search for specific elements

Comment: If you select the element you want to query with XPath then you can use a similar XPath to what you have on the selected element minus the //.

I've edited the answer to add code that solves a similar problem.