# Merge XML nodes in document

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have a XML-document created by MS Excel. What I want is to combine nodes with same id. The xml I currently have is something like this:

```
<ns1:publications>
<ns1:book id="3" subType="book">
    <ns1:peerReviewed>false</ns1:peerReviewed>
    <ns1:publicationCategory>scientific</ns1:publicationCategory>
    <ns1:publicationStatus>published</ns1:publicationStatus>
    <ns1:language>en_GB</ns1:language>
    <ns1:title>
        <ns2:text lang="en" country="EN">Kirja3</ns2:text>
    </ns1:title>
    <ns1:abstract>
        <ns2:text lang="en" country="EN">
    </ns1:abstract>
    <ns1:persons>
        <ns1:author>
            <ns1:role>author</ns1:role>
            <ns1:person external="false" id="3">
                <ns1:firstName>Rob</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>Hubbard</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
        </ns1:author>
    </ns1:persons>
    <ns1:organisations>
        <ns1:organisation id="220400"/>
    </ns1:organisations>
    <ns1:owner id="220400"/>
    <ns1:publicationDate>
        <ns2:year>2014</ns2:year>
    </ns1:publicationDate>
    <ns1:visibility>Public</ns1:visibility>
    <ns1:numberOfPages>655</ns1:numberOfPages>
    <ns1:placeOfPublication>Newcastle</ns1:placeOfPublication>
</ns1:book>
<ns1:book id="3">
    <ns1:title/>
    <ns1:abstract/>
    <ns1:persons>
        <ns1:author>
            <ns1:person id="4">
                <ns1:firstName>Chris</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>Steward</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
        </ns1:author>
    </ns1:persons>
    <ns1:organisations>
        <ns1:organisation id="220400"/>
    </ns1:organisations>
    <ns1:owner id="220400"/>
    <ns1:publicationDate/>
</ns1:book>
```

And it should be something like this:

```
<ns1:publications>
<ns1:book id="3" subType="book">
    <ns1:peerReviewed>false</ns1:peerReviewed>
    <ns1:publicationCategory>scientific</ns1:publicationCategory>
    <ns1:publicationStatus>published</ns1:publicationStatus>
    <ns1:language>en_GB</ns1:language>
    <ns1:title>
        <ns2:text lang="en" country="EN">Kirja3</ns2:text>
    </ns1:title>
    <ns1:abstract>
        <ns2:text lang="en" country="EN">
    </ns1:abstract>
    <ns1:persons>
        <ns1:author>
            <ns1:role>author</ns1:role>
            <ns1:person external="false" id="3">
                <ns1:firstName>Rob</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>Hubbard</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
        </ns1:author>
        <ns1:author>
            <ns1:person external="false" id="4">
                <ns1:firstName>Chris</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>Steward</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
        </ns1:author>
    </ns1:persons>
    <ns1:organisations>
        <ns1:organisation id="220400"/>
        <ns1:organisation id="220300"/>
    </ns1:organisations>
    <ns1:owner id="220400"/>
    <ns1:publicationDate>
        <ns2:year>2014</ns2:year>
    </ns1:publicationDate>
    <ns1:visibility>Public</ns1:visibility>
    <ns1:numberOfPages>655</ns1:numberOfPages>
    <ns1:placeOfPublication>Newcastle</ns1:placeOfPublication>
</ns1:book>
```

Data comes from Excel spreadsheet that has information on rows. For example book can have multiple authors and they are on separate rows with same id on first column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use xml serialization to import your data from xml, manipulate your data through c# classes and output it in xml format. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566602/how-do-i-return-all-elements-from-a-xml-doc/28569261#28569261) for more informations.

That is how you read:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass;
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    myObject = (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Once ou got the class, it would be easy to merge/remove nodes through linq or loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, C# is little over the top for this particular problem (work related, no way to have C# installed, and somewhat rusty skillset).